# C# Outlook get CompanyName property from Recipient

Tags: c#, outlook, add-in

I am currently writing an Outlook 2010 AddIn using C#. What I want is to get the CompanyName property from a Recipient object that I pull from an AppointmentItem. So, having the Recipients of an AppointmentItem I want to find out the CompanyName of each Recipient, which might be an ExchangeUser.

My code is this:

```
Recipients recipients = appointmentItem.Recipients;
foreach (Recipient rec in recipients)
{
    resolved = rec.Resolve();
    if (resolved)
    {
       ContactItem contactItem = rec.AddressEntry.GetContact();
       String companyName = contactItem.CompanyName;       
       // ...
    }
```

Where contactItem is always null.

Doing something like this also results in a null pointer.

```
ExchangeUser u = rec.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser();
companyName = u.CompanyName;
```

I simply cannot get to the CompanyName information. I know the information does exist. However, also a lot of other attributes, besides CompanyName, seem to result in NULL pointers as well.

Can someone give me a hint on that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with below code. Working for me.

**CODE:**

```
 bool resolved;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application olApplication = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();

        // get nameSpace and logon.
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpace olNameSpace = olApplication.GetNamespace("mapi");
        olNameSpace.Logon("Outlook", "", false, true);

        // get the Calender items
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder _olCalender = olNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);

        // Get the Items (Appointments) collection from the Calendar folder.
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Items oItems = _olCalender.Items;



        foreach (object o in oItems)
        {

            if (o is Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AppointmentItem)
            {
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Recipients recipients = ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AppointmentItem)o).Recipients;
                foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Recipient rec in recipients)
                {
                    resolved = rec.Resolve();
                    if (resolved)
                    {
                        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ContactItem contactItem = rec.AddressEntry.GetContact();
                        MessageBox.Show(contactItem.CompanyName);
                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

Hope It should work.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this but it may help. It looks like CompanyName is a property of a ContactItem, so you need to convert the recipient to a ContactItem. The below code looks for the contact in the address book using the recipient's email address. From here you may be able to find the CompanyName:

```
Outlook.MAPIFolder fldContacts = (Outlook.MAPIFolder)OutlookApp.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts); 
for (int i =1; i <aitem.Recipients.Count+1 ; i++) 
{ 
   Outlook.Recipient r = aitem.Recipients.Item(i); 
   if (!r.Resolved) r.Resolve(); 
   if (r.Resolved) 
   { 
     Outlook.ContactItem ci = (fldContacts.Items.Find("[Email1Address] = '" + r.Address + "'") as Outlook.ContactItem);
     if (ci != null) 
     { 
       //Now you got the contact deal with it here 
     } 
    }
}
```